# Need help Fixing these errors with classes

Tags: c++, c++11

I need help understanding these error. I have been  trying to figure out but can't get to working. Is my algorithm for adding even right?

Here is my current error:

> 'dem' was not declared in this scope.

I thought the header file takes care of the initialization.

Rational.h

```
#ifndef _RATIONAL_H_
#define _RATIONAL_H_
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Rational
{


    int num; //p
    int dem; // q


public:

Rational();

Rational(int P, int Q = 1);

void display() const; // _p:_q

void add(const Rational&);

};
#endif
```

Rational.cpp

```
#include "Rational.h"
int main()


{

    Rational r1(1 ,2);
    Rational r2(1,4);
    r1.add(r2);
    r1.display();


}
void add(const Rational&h2)
{

    int  i, k;
    Rational fract;
    add(h2);

    i = dem;
    k = h2.dem;
    num*= k;
    dem*=k;
    num = +r2.num*i;
    //return

}
```

Comment: When you make the assignment `i = dem;` you are referring to an instance variable without an actual instance.

Comment: instance variable can hold different values. I still don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  You are referencing the variable `dem` in `Rational.cpp` and it has not been defined there, nor is this a member of an instantiated class.

Answer (score 3):

You're defining `add()` as a global free function, not the member function of class `Rational`. So you can't access the member variable `dem` in it.

Change

```
void add(const Rational&h2)
{
...
```

to

```
void Rational::add(const Rational&h2)
{
...
```